# Worldwide standard textbooks vs textbooks from one's home country vs lecture notes by various people - pros and cons

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks, general-pedagogy

So far I've had three types of professors in my undergrad studies when it comes to choosing the main text for the course:
**Type A:** these are the professors who pick some standard textbook(s) in English that is(are) world renowned and will mostly use this(these) as the main source for the material they teach and they will rigorously follow it. Examples of such textbooks would be Do Carmo's Differential Geometry text or Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis aka "baby Rudin".
**Type B:** these are those who pick some textbook written in our native language that is more or less a traditional book for the subject in our country and follow it (or them if they choose more than one book, but this is rare in this typology) just like the people in Type A. Most of these professors pick such a textbook that is usually published by the publishing house of our university, so I would call these "local" texts. In case you are wondering, I live in southeast Europe, so we are not talking about books written in some international language, this is why I won't include examples.
**Type C:** those who write their own lecture notes (following various textbooks that may also appear in Type A or Type B classes that I described above). By write I don't necessarily mean write them in LaTeX and provide us with some book-like PDF. Most of them actually just write their notes on the blackboard (well, the virtual board nowadays) and we copy them down.
I wonder which of these approaches is actually the best. I've had classes that fall in either of these types that were really good and I can say that I learnt a lot of things, but I am unsure which is the best (I am mostly wondering due to my interest in pedagogy). I've heard Type A or Type C professors claiming that the books used by Type B professors are bad simply because they are not well established texts around the world. But I think that anyone's lecture notes are subject to the same criticism because after all the textbooks mentioned in Type B (and I think most textbooks in the world) originated from some lecture notes. I am curious what your experience has been with taking/giving classes that fall in either of these types. I feel that Type A classes are the best becuse their content is standard and thorough. The textbooks I mentioned in Type B are also thorough most of the times, but they certainly do contain more typos and mistakes then the standard texts on the subject that is taught. The Type C approach usually feels like the most lightweight of all of them simply because those lecture notes will 90% of the times be exactly what is covered in class, so you don't really learn anything new by reading them, they come in handy only if you miss class and you want to know exactly what the lecturer discussed.

Comment: I think the answer is yes. As in, all the above approaches can succeed or fail depending on the audience and instructor. Incidentally, there are also lecture notes which cover more than most books and/or more challenging idiosyncratic topics. Probably my Calculus III notes illustrate this: http://www.supermath.info/CalculusIIIf2014.pdf

Comment: @JamesS.Cook thanks for your input. Really nice lecture notes, I have never actually had lecturers that prepare so thorough notes. I now tend to believe that any of the approaches may indeed prove to be as successful as the others if done properly.

Comment: My experience has been almost entirely Type A, but not quite like you describe. In my case, I would have to divide Type A into several subtypes. For example, Type A1 is what you describe, Type A2 is using a well known text but covering less than half of the text because the famous text chosen is far more advanced and/or comprehensive than the course it is being used for, Type A3 is using a well known text but covering less than half of the text in order to have time to cover special topics of interest to the instructor. BTW, for each of these subtypes, I've both taken and taught such a class.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro thanks, your comment is definitely on spot, I didn't realize that we actually have all these subtypes (even though I now realize that I encountered them). So, what would you say of your experience with any of the types/subtypes? Do you feel that any of them is better?

Comment: Any of the 3 can be good or bad, depending on the teacher, but if someone had to pick one of them without knowing anything about the teacher or the class, then I think most anyone would pick Type A1.

Comment: Regarding classes I've taught: Type A2 occurred when I was hired after the text was chosen and the text was not appropriate for the class. Type A3 occurred when I taught a class in which everyone had a fair amount of previous background in the subject -- Some (not all) of the "topics of interest to the instructor" are [topic 1](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/-qQj8KG6bd8/m/Q-m9vsY2SS4J) and [topic 2](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/XDqhJxpURJM/m/oXjWQxoVFyIJ) and [topic 3](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/AlnNLGULurM/m/AOZSY2SWJXMJ) **(continued)**

Comment: and [topic 4](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/M_rwL68ibPs/m/WokSnPuvazsJ) and [topic 5](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/fzR4NkHf88M/m/qR4u1kfFCbIJ).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro thanks for your input, I really like seeing what others think about different ways of teaching math even though I am still a student and there are still some years until I will be an instructor myself :).

Comment: What kind of answer would you accept? Are you looking for research done in this direction, data on what is most common, or individual instructors' opinions?

Comment: @ChrisCunningham well, to be frank, either of those is great if well written and backed up :). I think that when I posted this I was more thinking of individual instructors' opinions, I hadn't thought that someone may have done some research into this.

Comment: At my university (in the US), type A is almost never appropriate because type A textbooks are too difficult for most of our students to understand.  My university is about average for a US university.  Unfortunately, there is a long tradition of using textbooks as guides for the instructor in what to lecture on, not as resources that any but the best students are able to use.

Comment: Do Carmo's Differential Geometry is a bad example of a textbook in English because it was written in Portuguese.